# Best practice to put component tree at NextJS13 app dir

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, directory

**Whats the best practice to put your components at?**

What would you recommend?

**Few examples of my ideas**

Ex. 1 (seems messy to me)

```
root/
├─ app/
│  ├─ signup/
│  │  ├─ page.tsx
│  │  ├─ LoginForm.tsx (component)
│  ├─ layout.tsx
│  ├─ page.tsx
│  ├─ Dropdown.tsx (component)
│  ├─ Navigation.tsx (component)
```

Ex. 2

```
app/
├─ components/
│  ├─ Navigation.tsx (component)
│  ├─ Dropdown.tsx (component)
├─ signup/
│  ├─ components/
│  │  ├─ LoginForm.tsx (component)
│  ├─ page.tsx
├─ layout.tsx
├─ page.tsx
```

Ex. 3

```
app/
├─ signup/
│  ├─ page.tsx
├─ layout.tsx
├─ page.tsx
components/
├─ home/
│  ├─ signup/
│  │  ├─ LoginForm.tsx (component)
│  ├─ Dropdown.tsx (component)
│  ├─ Navigation.tsx (component)
```